# ABBYY FineReader Engine API Resources

Tags: sdk, finereader, abbyy

Does any one worked with ABBYY FineReader Engine 9.0 API? There are almost no resources available on internet. The only thing is the developer reference help file installed along with it. But that is not sufficient enough.

Comment: You can ask ABBYY: http://www.abbyy.com/sdk/?param=31282

Comment: You're intitled to free technical support for the trial period if you have purchased a license. You can also signup for a technical support plan for support beyond that period. See http://www.abbyy.com/sdk/?param=30656 for details.

Comment: https://forum.ocrsdk.com/thread/5178-abby-fine-reader-engine-11-sdk-c-documentation/