# ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine for Iphone

Tags: iphone, mobile, ocr, abbyy

I am looking to use/buy a OCR solution for my next iPhone app.

Searching through the answers on this site didn't really help me a lot.

Did anybody ever use ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine for iPhone?

What interests me is how good is it (recognition) and how much does it cost?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try contacting this user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336822/abbyy-finereader-engine-api-resources/1660465#1660465

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find anyone who actually used the mobile SDK, however pricing wise I think I got an idea.

It's around 15K + 20% off of the revenue (after Apple takes 30%, so you are left with 50%).

Comment: ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK also can be used on the iPhone and its cost starts at $9,99. More info here: http://ocrsdk.com

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who ends up at this thread looking for a general iPhone OCR solution (I realize this thread was originally ABBYY specific), there's a good Tesseract proof of concept app here: http://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Tesseract (open source). 
[This site](http://sites.google.com/site/olipion/cross-compilation/tesseract-ocr)  describes compiling it for the iPhone.

Comment: Well, then you should download the trial http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/trial and contact them for a price quote.

Comment: I did that, I mean contacting them about the price. It's just that I was curious if other developers used it. Also this post would be nice for others to see in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [OCRopus?](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/)

Comment: Well, this looks like something built by Google on top of Tesseract. Still not an iPhone solution.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on the mobile version of this, but I have written an application using ABBYY before, and the recognition performance was quite good. We were looking at processing contracts.. After twice refaxing them, we still got around only about 5 characters errors per 10 pages (without rotating the documents).

Comment: What was the licencing cost of ABBYY if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea, and contacted them to ask for prices.

1000$ per year for the basic engine, another 1000$ if you want to use their business card module + up to 50% of each sale!!!

very cheap, isnt it? dont think about using the engine if you are not quite sure to sell at least 10.000 apps a year...

Comment: Are you sure it was $1,000 and not $10,000? While googleing and searching I found that it's around 10K (pay just once) + 20% of each sale. Maybe it depends on the country. Anyway I don't think I'll use them.

Comment: I contacted them for a price and all they would do was try get me to use the product and once there was a level of buy in only then would they tell me the price. I hate that model of pricing so I will never use them. Saying that they now have a cloud ocr which is transparently priced so that may suit some people and applications which don't need scanning offline.